# Long press the center button on the D-Pad for Android TV app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a small application for Android TV. It needs to implement calling an additional menu when the center button is Longpressed.

All attempts to find solutions have been unsuccessful.

If you have a solution for this problem - please share.

I tried to use the built-in Longpress functions in the standard Flutter widgets. To no avail.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick solution

```
  Focus(
                autofocus: true,
                onKey: (fnode, key) {
                  if ((key.logicalKey.keyLabel == "Select") && (key.repeat)) {
                     ///code for Long press 
                    return KeyEventResult.handled;
                  }
                  return KeyEventResult.ignored;
                },
                child: childWidget(params),
);
```

You can replace the "childWidget(params)" with your own widget tree.
And add code for long press event.
Hope this is clear.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).